# multi-window - is it possible to make an app smaller than 33% of screen?

Tags: android

I'm using Android [multi-window](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window) to display 2 apps on screen.  I want one app (Google Maps/Waze/etc.) to occupy 90% of the screen and the other 10% (my music player UI).

However, the window divider/slider does not really allow this.  If an app is made smaller than about 33% of the screen then Android will "close" that app.  The phone is in portrait mode running Android 8.0.

In my music player app's layout file I've set `android:layout_height` and `android:defaultHeight` values (to 96dp or so) to no avail.  I've also tried adding `<layout>` values for the activity in the manifest.  No dice.

Is there a way to enable a 90/10 split (programmatically or via XML layout)?  I'd even settle for an ADB command that "relaxes" the 33% mark.